# Measuring a voltage signal ranging from -2 to 2 volts into a 16 bit ADC circuit

Tags: operational-amplifier, sensor, negative

I'm trying to read a voltage that represents a signal from a sensor. This signal can range between -2 volts to +2 volts. I wanted to read this signal to log it, but most ADCs (including ones on an Arduino) can't handle the negative values.

I wanted to make a circuit that could do this for me instead. I started with a circuit that would provide me with polarity detection and also a magnitude rectifier using two op-amps, and then read those two signals and post-process them on an Arduino. See the image below of the original circuit.

[image: Detection circuit]

This didn't really work as well as I thought it would so I decided to make a circuit that could add a reference voltage of +2.5V to the input signal and then read that. See the image below.

[image]

I'm not sure if either circuit is correct or what the correct way of doing this is.

Comment: I think some indirect current feedback instrumental amplifier could do the trick.

Comment: @gjossep  For the sake of completeness, what's the sensor?  Tell us the nature of the sensor, or the model number.

Comment: @NickAlexeev The sensor is a JCI 140 Field mill [link](https://dekraprod-media.e-spirit.cloud/d6df64f5-b4d9-468c-8ffa-874a167a15ab/media/dekra-instruments-brochure-2023.pdf), which can measure the atmospheric electricity up till ±20kV.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This ridiculously simple resistor divider will produce an output between +0.24V and +3.0V for inputs going from -2.0V to +2.0V respectively:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmtc3L.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image]

If you have a noisy +5V supply, it will inject some of that noise directly into the signal, though. This won't be a problem if your ADC uses the same supply (+5V in this case), or some fixed fraction of that supply, for its own internal reference voltage. If the ADC contains a precision reference, you'll get better results by using that instead of +5V, or by providing your own reference. Below I use the well loved TL431 to obtain a rock-steady +4.2V:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzIjmM.png)</sup>

The output impedance of those last two designs is several kilohms. A typical microcontroller ADC would not have a problem with this, but yours might. You can buffer the signal with a voltage follower which will have an output impedance near zero. You could use any op-amp with inputs and output that can get near the negative supply, like the LM358, LM324, TLC2272 etc:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKJYKM.png)</sup>

With careful choice of resistances and op-amp, it's possible to use a single op-amp to offset, scale *and* buffer the signal. This next circuit produces a +4.8V to +0.2V output (it inverts) in response to -2.0V to +2.0V in:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fp33WR.png)</sup>

This requires an op-amp with an output capable of approaching both supply rails, of which the TLC2272 is an example. The +1.16V source V2 can be obtained using a voltage divider across the +5V and 0V supplies, or using a precision reference like the TL431. Here's the response:

[image]

Not all input ranges can be accommodated with this particular op-amp configuration, but your symmetrical ±2V input is easy to work with; in particular you'll notice that no negative supplies are needed in any of the above solutions.